# Python public methods inside classes?

Tags: python, class

I cutted out code for better understanding my issue. The question is if there is some way how to create something like public method and how or whether I'm totally misunderstood OOP concept.

I have a major class `PlayerWindow` which only plays video. Then there is class `ControlsWindow` serving only for my developing, testing and maintenance purposes (launched when fullscreen off). Therefore, I want to be it particularly. Can not figure out, how to call method `play()` from the `ControlsWindow` class as well like from inside because when I initialize `ControlsWindow` with instance of `PlayerWindow` then I get infinite loop.

```
class ControlsWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
    super(ControlsWindow, self).__init__()

    self.playPauseButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Play', self)
    self.show()


class PlayerWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
    super(PlayerWindow, self).__init__()

    # ...
    self.mediaPlayer = self.playerInstance.media_player_new() 
    # ... 
    self.initUI()
    self.play()

  def initUI(self):
    # ...
    self.show()
    self.controls_window = ControlsWindow()         

  def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
      self.toggleControlsWindow()

  def toggleControlsWindow(self):
    if self.isFullScreen():
      self.showNormal()
      self.controls_window = ControlsWindow()      
    else:
      self.controls_window.close()           
      self.showFullScreen()

  def play(self):
    self.mediaPlayer.play()


def main():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  player_window = PlayerWindow()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())               


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an instance of `PlayerWindow` to the class constructor of `ControlsWindow`:

```
class ControlsWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

  def __init__(self, parent):  # Notice the new parent argument
    super(ControlsWindow, self).__init__()
    self.parent = parent

    self.playPauseButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Play', self)
    self.show()

    # Now you can call the parent's (PlayerWindow) play() function:
    self.parent.play()


class PlayerWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
    super(PlayerWindow, self).__init__()

    # ...
    self.mediaPlayer = self.playerInstance.media_player_new() 
    # ... 
    self.initUI()
    self.play()

  def initUI(self):
    # ...
    self.show()
    self.controls_window = ControlsWindow(self)  # Pass a reference of PlayerWindow

  def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
      self.toggleControlsWindow()

  def toggleControlsWindow(self):
    if self.isFullScreen():
      self.showNormal()
      self.controls_window = ControlsWindow(self)  # Pass a reference of PlayerWindow
    else:
      self.controls_window.close()           
      self.showFullScreen()

  def play(self):
    self.mediaPlayer.play()


def main():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  player_window = PlayerWindow()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())               


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looked for! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understand you correctly and your code can be simplified to something like:

```
# QtGui.QWidget
class B:
    pass

# ControlsWindow
class Test(B):
    def __init__(self):
        # You want to call Actual.play here?
        pass

# PlayerWindow
class Actual(B):
    def __init__(self):
        # Your self.mediaPlayer = self.playerInstance.media_player_new()
        self.some_variable = 42

    def play(self):
        print(self.some_variable)
```

If you'd like to call `Actual.play` method from inside `Test` class you can either:

make `Actual.play` static and `self.mediaPlayer` a class variable

```
class Test(B):
    def __init__(self):
        # Here you go!
        Actual.play()

class Actual(B):
    # mediaPlayer = self.playerInstance.media_player_new()
    some_variable = 42

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def play():
        print(Actual.some_variable)
```

or pass a reference to `PlayerWindow` object to your `ControlsWindow` class instance

```
class B:
    pass

class Test(B):
    def __init__(self, actual: Actual):
        # Here you go!
        actual.play()

class Actual(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_variable = 42

    def play(self):
        print(self.some_variable)
```

Comment: As well useful solution! I appreciate. Thanks